# Xcode 7 - Localising the storyboard doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an application that must support two languages: english and french. 
English is the Development Language and I also added French.

I have three children below the Main.storyboard: Main.storyboard(Base), Main.storyboard(English) and Main.storyboard(French). Unfortunately the Main.storyboard(Base) has the texts in french and my English file is ignored.

How can I fix this? I struggle already for 2 hours. When I run the application all the texts are in french tough the device language is english.

I tried to change all the strings in the base storyboard to be in english but after that some of the french texts from Main.storyboard(french) are ignored. It driving me nuts.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does your strings file contain the properly mapped identifiers-string pair that correspond to the user interface in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I checked the objectIds for the items I want to localize their texts. Anyway I have found a solution but it isn't too good. I deleted the base internationalization  and the storyboard too and I imported it again from another location where I have made a copy. Then I localized again the storyboard file and now it seems to be good. But I have to assign again every string.